# Runaway docker logs not being rotated by docker-compose despite "max-size" command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Rails project I run with docker-compose in production. There are a lot of logs, and they are filling up all the space of my docker container within a few days. Running `du --block-size=1M -a /var/lib/docker/`, it shows these large, and constantly growing log files:

`10543  /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cd749947f8cda9fa2b2cd14c0f1a2af88da66c43b2d4424e13c787d27dd0e41c/merged/dockerapp/log/production.log 10543   /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cd749947f8cda9fa2b2cd14c0f1a2af88da66c43b2d4424e13c787d27dd0e41c/diff/dockerapp/log/production.log`

Following the instructions for docker-compose v3 files, I am trying to limit the file size and rotate using the following commands:

`logging: driver: "local" options: max-size: "15m" max-file: "3"`

But even with that in the docker-compose file (I've tried the json driver too), the logs continue to grow until they take up all of my docker container's free space. How can I resolve this?

Comment: After making the logging change, did you stop and remove the container?

Comment: Yes, the container is rebuilt on the servers on every deployment

Comment: So the newly deployed container HAS free space but runs out of it eventually? Did you try removing and recreating + redeploying the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker logging options affect container's standard output & error streams, which are stored in a file near the container, but not inside its file system. You can see this log with `docker logs CONTAINER` command.

Your `production.log` seems like a regular file and thus, it won't be rotated automatically unless you implement this as part of your application/container.

The best thing you can do is to direct your logs to the output or error stream **of the main process** inside the container. **Assuming you don't use host's PID namespace**, you can try logging into one of these:

```
/proc/1/fd/1  # stdout of the first proc
/proc/1/fd/2  # stderr of the first proc
```

Regardless of PID namespace, these are safe to try:

```
# might not work with forking apps
/dev/stdout   # stdout of the current proc
/dev/stderr   # stderr of the current proc
```

You will know if it worked if you are able to see logs with `docker logs` command.

Also, instead of using one of the streams directly, some (nginx, for example) prefer making symlinks to them. If you have a startup script inside the container, you can try adding this:

```
ln -sf /dev/stdout /full/path/to/production.log
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've made the change in my production logger and seeing if that fixed things. One thing to note though, is that I was already able to see my logs by doing `docker logs CONTAINER` before even making this change, which makes me think there's something else going on.

Comment: @D-Nice The fact that you were able to see logs before making changes tells that something writes to the stream. It might be something like `tail -f production.log` in the startup script, or maybe it's just the application writing to several places simultaneously, or it can be completely different logs. I suggest you investigate that.

Comment: Regardless of what else is happening, redirecting my production logs to `/proc/1/fd/1` fixed the issue for me, so I'm marking this as the correct answer. Thanks!